# UIPageViewController as application's root controller

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UIPageViewController` for the first time. It's of course, iOS5 and I'm comfortable with ARC. I'm *not* using Storyboards.

In all the piecemeal examples I see, the `UIPageViewController` never "owns" the screen. It is always the child of some other view controller. Is this a requirement? I want to make it the root controller of my app, much like is commonly done with `UINavigationController`. I'm trying to set it all up programmatically, but all I get is an empty page view controller, with no content in it.

Here's how the app starts off (all code here is in my app delegate class):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self configureLoggers];
    [self applyAppearanceProxySettings];
    [self configureDataStore];
    [self configureNavigationController];
    [self configurePageController];    // <-- this is where we do the page view controller setup, shown next.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.pageController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    log4Info(@"Application completed launching.");

    return YES;
}
```

And that method mentioned in the code above, that does the setup for the Page View Controller:

```
- (void)configurePageController {
    CCFrontCoverViewController *frontCoverViewController = [[CCFrontCoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin]
                                                    forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                                                      navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                    options:options];

    self.pageController.delegate = self;
    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // So we know we're missing content because red shows through.

    NSArray *pageViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frontCoverViewController, self.navigationController, nil];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:pageViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I've also put logging in the two data source callback methods, and they don't even get called.

When this is run, I just get a blank red screen. Again, there's no storyboard involved. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?  Are you sure that self.navigationController isn't nil?

Comment: I have an assertion to confirm that self.navigationController isn't nil at the point I add it to the page view controller's stack of controllers. The only error I see, I've seen people dismiss on the Apple dev forums as a bug, which is this: "The view controller <UIPageViewController: 0xce786f0> returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation."

Comment: See [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/563625#563625) discussion in the Apple Developer Forums regarding that error message (I read it as saying the UIPageViewController will return `NO` to all orientations any time it is not set up properly...).

Comment: Good find! So that message really is an indication that something isn't set up properly, despite it not being clear on the root cause at issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to use a `UIPageViewController` as the root view controller in a sample project provided that:

- The `UIPageViewController` is initialized properly with a valid spine location.
- The `UIPageViewController`'s `doubleSided` property is set (consistent with the spine location).
- The `UIPageViewController`'s `viewControllers` array is set (again, consistent with the spine location and `doubleSided` property).

It looks like you haven't set `doubleSided` to `YES` in your code (since your `viewControllers` array has two items in it).  Does adding that before you set the `viewControllers` array fix your problem?

**EDIT:** Just for posterity, in the [UIPageViewController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) there is a chart in the description of the `setViewControllers:direction:animation:completion:` method showing the number of view controllers allowed for all valid combinations of spine location and `doubleSided`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The tipping point for me is your mention of setting viewControllers correctly. I thought we could give an arbitrary starting set, but when we're not going double sided nor two-up, but just plain old single page turning, we should only provide *one* initial view controller, and let the data source methods for next/previous page take it from there. Good checklist to ensure we've set it up right!

Comment: Right. You only ever put one or two view controllers in the array you provide to `setViewControllers:` depending on how many pages your UIPageViewController displays at once.